# Minimize the number of outputs

Tags: python, pulp

For a linear optimization problem, I would like to include a penalty. The penalty of every option (penalties[(i)]) should be 1 if the the sum is larger than 0 and 0 if the penalty is zero. Is there a way to do this?

The penalty is defined as:

```
penalties = {}
for i in A: 
    penalties[(i)]=(lpSum(choices[i][k] for k in B))/len(C)
prob += Objective Function + sum(penalties)
```

For example:

```
penalties[(0)]=0
penalties[(1)]=2
penalties[(3)]=6
penalties[(4)]=0
```

The sum of the penalties should then be:

```
sum(penalties)=0+1+1+0= 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. What you need to do is to create binary variables: `use_ith_row`. The interpretation of this variable will be `==1` if any of the `choices[i][k]` are >= 0 for row `i` (and 0 otherwise).

The penalty term in your objective function simply needs to be `sum(use_ith_row[i] for i in A)`.

The last thing you need is the set of constraints which enforce the rule described above:

```
for i in A:
    lpSum(choices[i][k] for k in B) <= use_ith_row[i]*M
```

Finnaly, you need to choose M large enough so that the constraint above has no limiting effect when `use_ith_row` is 1 (you can normally work out this bound quite easily). Choosing an `M` which is way too large will also work, but will tend to make your problem solve slower.

p.s. I don't know what `C` is or why you divide by its length - but typically if this penalty is secondary to you other/primary objective you would weight it so that improvement in your primary objective is always given greater weight.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Based on your explanation I would do the following: 
    
    `use_ith_row = np.zeros(len(A))
    for i in A: 
          if lpSum(choices[i][k] for k in B) >=1:
               use_ith_row[i]=1
           prob+= lpSum(choices[i][k] for k in B) <= use_ith_row[i]*10`

Furthermore, I have updated the objective function:
        
    `prob += OBJECTIVE + sum(use_ith_row[i] for i in A)`

However this doesn't give the expected output. Could you tell me whether i do something wrong?

Comment: You don't need the if statement. This is built into the constraint. If `use_ith_row` is 1 then the constraint will not be binding. If it's zero it will contain choices to 0.